# Ubuntu 18.04 Backup Failed

Tags: backup

After upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 my backups are still not working to my external HD. I am still using the "Backups" program that worked fine in U16.04. After removing non-ASCII characters as suggested on a different thread, which did decrease my error messages from many to one, I get the new error message: "InvalidBackendURL: missing // - relative paths not supported for scheme invalid: invalid://"

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Seems there is a new issue with the backup program. During the timed backup, I get an error message: "Backup Failed - InvalidBackendURL: missing // - relative paths not supported for scheme invalid: invalid://"